# HTML Form don't let me fill it with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and I need to fill in this form and then click the button to login. Hope someone could guide me into the right direction of why it's not working.

On practically any other site I've tested, it works fine (basically just switching out the "Id's") - but not on this particular site.
The site is not available for public so I can't provide the URL for it.

The problem is if I manually fill username and password and then from the web console use the .click event below, the login works fine.

When I use the .value event to fill username and password, I can see both fields gets filled but when .click event happens, it triggers the login and it seems to work but after a few seconds, it just says invalid username and password, like if I typed the wrong username and password.

Since I can't see the password in clear text from the form, I don't know if it's right or not but if I use the console from the web browser, I can see both username and password returns the correct values.

I'm using the following code:

```js
function doStuff(){
        document.getElementById('loginUsername').value = "username@email.com";
        document.getElementById('password').value = "password123"
        document.getElementsByClassName('button ok')[0].click();
    }
    doStuff();
```

```html
<form data-v-d9a0abfc="" data-v-48366e1e="" role="form" class="form loginForm">
      <h2 data-v-d9a0abfc="" role="region" class="visuallyhidden">Login form</h2>
      <label data-v-d9a0abfc="" for="loginUsername" class="loginLabel">Username</label>
      <input data-v-d9a0abfc="" spellcheck="false" type="text" id="loginUsername" name="loginUsername" autofocus="autofocus" class="form-control loginField">
      <label data-v-d9a0abfc="" for="password" class="loginLabel">Password</label>
      <input data-v-d9a0abfc="" type="password" id="password" name="password" autofocus="autofocus" class="form-control loginField">
      <div data-v-d9a0abfc="" class="">
        <div data-v-304a83cb="" data-v-d9a0abfc="" role="alert" aria-relevant="additions removals" style="display: none;">
        </div>
        <div data-v-7224d6b7="" data-v-d9a0abfc="" class="ace-button" id="accept-button">
          <button data-v-7224d6b7="" aria-describedby="11" tabindex="0" type="button" class="button ok">
          Login
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: it's possible the website uses a framework that listens to the input onchange and stores it in memory. But when you update the value programatically, onchange is not triggered. Then at submit time, it sends the value in memory instead of the value that you added programatically. If you look at the network tab of the dev tool you might see if the login request and see the value that are sent to the backend (assuming they don't hash it before sending them to the backend)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the website stores the input value in memory by listening to the input `onchange` callback. Then when clicking on the submit button, it sends the in memory value instead of the one you set programatically. This is not triggered when you programatically update the input value.
What you could try is to programatically trigger the `change` Event like this:

```
function doStuff(){
    var usernameInput = document.getElementById('loginUsername');
    usernameInput.value = "username@email.com";
    usernameInput.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
    var passwordInput = document.getElementById('password');
    passwordInput.value = "password123";
    passwordInput.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
    document.getElementsByClassName('button ok')[0].click();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, sounds very likely the website stores it in memory. Tried your suggestion above and with variations but nothing seems to work :(
Think I need to give up.. its so close but so far....

Answer (score 0):

As a comment pointed out already, i suspect a Framework is handling the Frontend. It could also be, that there is just an `onChange` Event or an `onInput` Event tracking the Value and already working some validation or something in the background.

I've put together an example why your code would fail.
If there is an EventListener inplace, to track the Inputs and handling the values somewhere else, you could emit the Event yourself after setting the value. This should do the trick, if there is a separate handling inplace.

```js
let username = undefined;
let password = undefined;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  
  // Code to update a variable in the background.
  document.getElementById('textInput').addEventListener('change', updateUsername);
  document.getElementById('passInput').addEventListener('change', updatePassword);
  
  document.getElementById('btnSubmit').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    
    const text = document.getElementById('textInput').value;
    const pass = document.getElementById('passInput').value;    
    console.log(text,"|", pass);
    console.log(username,"|", password);
  });
  
  
  
  
  
  
    // Your code, to manipulate the Inputfields.
  const textInputEl = document.getElementById('textInput');
  textInputEl.value = "Test value ...";
  // This line triggers the change event, it could also be the 'input' event, depending which     // events gets listened to. With this, if there is an event in the background listened to, to 
  // track the Value, it should update the variable accordingly.
  // textInputEl.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
  
  const passInputEl = document.getElementById('passInput');
  passInputEl.value = "Test value ...";
  // Same line as above
  // passInputEl.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
  
});

function updateUsername(event){
  username = event.target.value;
}
function updatePassword(event) {
  password = event.target.value;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" id="textInput" />
  <input type="password" id="passInput" />
  <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
</div>
```